# Meaning of "and yet" in the middle of this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

From this passage in the Harry Potter series:

> He bought Harry a hamburger and they sat down on plastic seats to eat
>   them. Harry kept looking around. Everything looked so strange, somehow.
>   "You all right, Harry? Yer very quiet," said Hagrid.
>   Harry wasn't sure he could explain. He'd just had the best birthday of
>   his life -- **and yet** -- he chewed his hamburger, trying to find the
>   words.
>   "Everyone thinks I'm special," he said at last.

Does "yet" mean "still" or "in spite what has been said"?

Comment: Yes. It's a slightly more "formal, literary" alternative to plain ***but***.

Comment: Yes, "yet" means "still" and yes, in this context it means "in spite of what has been said".Try replacing "yes" in this quote with "still". The meaning does not change.

Comment: That is the narrator indirectly revealing Harry's thought. The words **and yet** say to the reader that Harry is trying to put into words the thing which is undermining his sense of well-being, the thing which would *contradict* the notion that all is well with the birthday-boy.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that it is "**in spite of**" but the implication is that in spite of his excellent day (*"the best birthday of his life"*), he hesitates and has to think before answering the question *"[Are] You all right, Harry?"*